# using sklearn.linearmodel to predict an x value

Tags: python, scikit-learn

using sklearn to predict clearly gives wrong answer

this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model

#read file
data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Administrator\OneDrive - Trøndelag fylkeskommune\Skrivebord\Scripts\POPULATION_NORWAY.csv")
data.head()

data=data [["YEAR","POPULATION"]]

print(data)

plt.scatter(data["YEAR"], data["POPULATION"] , color="blue")
plt.xlabel("YEAR")
plt.ylabel("POPULATION")
plt.show()

train=data[:(int((len(data))))]
test=data[(int((len(data)))):]

regr=linear_model.LinearRegression()

train_x=np.array(train[["YEAR"]])
train_y=np.array(train[["POPULATION"]])

regr.fit(train_x,train_y)

plt.scatter(train["YEAR"], train["POPULATION"], color="blue" )
plt.plot(train_x, regr.coef_*train_x+regr.intercept_, "-r")
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Population")
plt.show()


def get_regression_predictions(input_features,intercept,slope):
    predicted_values=input_features*slope+intercept

    return predicted_values


future_year=float(input("what year is it?"))
future_population=float(input("what is the population?"))


estimated_population=get_regression_predictions(future_year,regr.intercept_[0],regr.coef_[0][0])
print ("estimated population :",estimated_population)


estimated_year=get_regression_predictions(future_population,regr.intercept_[0],regr.coef_[0][0])
print ("estimated year :",estimated_year)
```

these are the values:

```
YEAR  POPULATION
1900       2.217
1910       2.376
1920       2.616
1930       2.799
1940       2.963
1950       3.249
1960       3.567
1970       3.863
1980       4.078
1990       4.233
2000       4.478
2010       4.858
2020       5.367
```

this is population number in millions in Norway

this is the input and output:

```
what year is it?2050 

what is the population?6 

estimated population : 5.8595164835164795  

estimated year : -45.6942065934066
```

as you can see, the estimated year is all wrong, i expect the estimated year to be someting closer to 2030

Comment: x-intercept and y-intercept don't use the same formula. `y = m * x + c`. So `x = (y - c)/m`. Use this formula and your answer should come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are approximating the population as function of time like this:
Pop = year*slope + intercepet

To get the year in function of population, you need invert the expression:

year = (pop - intercept)/slope